# asyncio.create_task vs await

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm having trouble understanding how the `asyncio.create_task()` function introduced in Python 3.7 is supposed to work.  If I do:

```
import asyncio

async def helloworld():
    print("Hello world from a coroutine!")
    asyncio.create_task(helloworld())

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(helloworld())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get:

`Hello world from a coroutine!
Hello world from a coroutine!`

As output (ie the coroutine is run twice).  How is this not infinite recursion though?  I'd expect to see what I see when I use the `await` keyword:

```
import asyncio


async def helloworld():
    print("Hello world from a coroutine!")
    await helloworld()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(helloworld())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With this I get:

`Hello world from a coroutine!
Hello world from a coroutine!
Hello world from a coroutine!
... many more lines...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "test3.py", line 48, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(helloworld())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test3.py", line 37, in helloworld
    await helloworld()
  File "test3.py", line 37, in helloworld
    await helloworld()
  File "test3.py", line 37, in helloworld
    await helloworld()
  [Previous line repeated 984 more times]
  File "test3.py", line 36, in helloworld
    print("Hello world from a coroutine!")
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

How is the `create_task` only being scheduled once, and what is the use case for when you might use it (since it has to be run within a context where the event loop is already running)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The task isn't scheduled once, but the loop only runs until `helloworld` is complete. You see the message print twice because the loop lets the next task run. After that, the tasks stop running because the loop isn't running anymore.

If you change

```
loop.run_until_complete(helloworld())
```

to

```
loop.create_task(helloworld())
loop.run_forever()
```

you'll see `Hello world from a coroutine!` print out repeatedly.

Comment: Right, so the 2nd time into `helloworld` we schedule another run of it, but because of the `run_until_complete` being done control is returned back to `main()`.  Thanks!

Comment: "You see the message print twice because the loop lets the next task run." -- is this by accident (undefined behavior under race condition), or is it the expected behaviour, like: finish all started tasks while silently ignoring new calls to `create_task`?

Comment: Does not explain why the loop only lets the next task run and not any subsequent tasks.

Comment: @GamefanA because once the first task registers the second task it's done. At that point, `run_until_,complete` is satisfied and stops running the loop.

Comment: @dirn Here is the scenario in my head. First task is ran, which prints and schedules the second task. If it is as you say and the first task is now done, then the loop should exit immediately and not even attempt the second, even though it is queued up. But that doesn't happen! its as if the first task doesn't terminate at the end, but instead yields and gives the second task a chance to run, which in turn schedules a third, and so on and so on... only explanation i could think of is that the first task yields to the second and the second yields back to the first and the first then terminates.

Comment: @GamefanA you need `run_forever` for that.

Comment: But why does the `await` example not terminate after the 2nd time the `helloworld` is scheduled via `await`? I.e. why is it treating `loop.run_until_complete` as `loop.run_forever`?

Comment: @user2340939 in the second example, `helloworld` doesn't complete until `await helloworld()` is complete, which doesn't complete until its `await helloworld()` is complete, and so on.

Comment: Ah of course, the first case doesn't call `await` on the task, i.e. `await asyncio.create_task(helloworld())`.

Answer (score 8):

You could treat `asyncio.create_task` as a daemon thread in a multi-threaded world. The loop stops when the "main" coroutine stops. So the other daemon threads just quits anyway.